# Fcm implementation in self made framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode9

I am new to the IOS development. I have created the app and Implemented the FCM in it. And notifications are working just fine as expected.

Now I have to make this whole code as a private framework. but I am really confused. The following is the thing that is what confused me

I have a workspace with the Framework and the multiple apps that depends on the Framework.You can think framework as a complete app.And the multiple apps are dependent on the framework and these multiple apps have no UI but starting the Framework app with the following things **(And these following things are what I am unable to do and are needed for each client app)**

- App Name
- App Icons
- App Colors
- And Ofcourse FCM plist google file for each client separately

So I really do not know How to make these things change for each client. Because I really do not know if there is something to be done for the shared resources to be get overrided by the Client app.

**So what should be done here? How can I fulfill these requirements? how can I achieve what I wanted?**

I hope that I am pretty clear in my questions. Please tell me how it can be done.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: no. I achieved it with targets

Comment: Could you please let me know how as i'm also new to iOS?

Comment: what is your case

Comment: implement FCM completely in SDK(framework) not in app

Comment: Well implementing in framework, I still have no workaround of it. But I get it VIA targets